# Command C do not stop local server from running on VS code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, localhost

I'm trying to stop my local server on VS code from running my react app (after using "npm run dev") by command C on the terminal.
It doesn't seem to work and the app is still running at my local host (and i don't get any feedback on the terminal that local server stopped).

Answer (score 1):

It's control + C ( Ctrl + C can confuse Mac users with windows Ctrl + C)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to stop the server from the terminal, try Ctrl-C instead.

Comment: I'm using Mac...isn't command-c is the equivalent to Ctrl-C ?

Comment: Yes, in Mac's terminal, you can still use many shortcuts like you would in a Linux bash terminal, on the Mac's terminal Cmd-C is for copying.

Comment: but that's what not working, I'm pressing cmd-c and i doesn't stop the server...

Comment: On Mac terminal, Cmd-C doesn't stop the server, Ctrl-C does

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your VsCode key bindings don't have a chord after Ctrl + C.

For example a Ctrl + C + I key binding will prevent a Ctrl + C from working.

Answer (score 0):

In Macbook using Ctrl+C (Command + C not working)